# Changing the value of form property in javascript with Struts 1.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts, struts-1

I have a problem and I have no idea how to solve it. I want to change properties of my form in javascript. I do it like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#submitCheckbox").click(function() {
    if($('#abc').prop('checked')==false){
        $('#abc').val(false);
        var a;
        a=$('#abc').val();
        alert(a);
    }
});
});
```

My JSP:(it's only part and it's in the form)

```
<html:checkbox property="abc" value="1" styleId="abc" />
            <bean:message key="label.form.abc" />
```

```
<html:submit styleClass="btn btn-primary" styleId="submitCheckbox">
                <bean:message key="button.continue" />
            </html:submit>
```

And in my action I have(abc is a property in the form and it has getter and setter and send value one correctly):

```
System.out.println(registration.isAbc());
```

Ok, so when I check a checkbox it sets abc value to 1(true). But then when I go to the next page and then go back to the one with checkboxes and I uncheck the one which was previously checked I want its value to be set to zero/false. Java script alert shows that the value is equal to false(so i think it changed) but when I go to the next page it's still equal to true(so it didnt't changed).

So, how can I change the value of form property in java script so that the form remembers it?

Comment: Do you have a method `getAbc()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden field to hold unchecked values

```
<html:hidden property="abc_unchecked"/>
```

with the same property type and values like `abc` but different name. Now, a javascript should modify its value when checkbox change state.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#abc").change(function() {
    if($("#abc").prop("checked")==false){
        $("#abc_unchecked").val(false);
        var a;
        a=$("#abc_unchecked").val();
        alert(a);
    } else {
        $("#abc_unchecked").val(true);
        var a;
        a=$("#abc_unchecked").val();
        alert(a);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Then in the action or in the form before validation you should check for unchecked value

```
if (isAbc_unchecked()) 
  setAbc(false);
} else {
  if(!isAbc()){
    setAbc(true);
  }
}
```